# What do these different sentences mean? "If you hadn't (didn't) lost your memory, you would have remembered me."

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

And which of them are correct? A girl had an accident, and she lost her memory(in the past), and she still hasn't retrieved her memories. This is fiction.

> 1- If you **hadn't** lost your memory, you would have remembered me.
>   2- If you **didn't** lose your memory, You would have remembered me.

Any better way to say it guys?

Comment: A hint: look for "conditional sentences" on the web. P.S. you can also use a double space instead of `<br>`

Comment: Is this a question of different level conditionals?  Seems that "didn't lose" calls for "would remember", and "hadn't lost" calls for "would have remembered"...  But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is good and I can't think of anything better.
2 isn't quite right, but something like it could work, "If you didn't lose your memory, you would remember me". For example:

> "If you didn't lose your memory every time you got drunk, you would remember 
>   me when I came to the pub to drive you home!"